# How to use react-error-boundary properly in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I have implemented one example of the `react-error-boundary` npm library. But it didn't seem to work properly.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';

function ErrorFallback({ error }) {
  return (
    <div role="alert">
      <p>Something went wrong:</p>
      <pre style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error.message}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

function Greeting({ subject }) {
  return <div>Hello {subject.toUpperCase()}</div>;
}

function Farewell({ subject }) {
  return <div>Goodbye {subject.toUpperCase()}</div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
      <Greeting />
      <Farewell />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error message is shown below:

[image]

It seems that the `ErrorFallback` component is not rendering. I think I am doing something wrong which breaks the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of error boundary during **development**. Press the close (X) button at the top right to hide the error stack and you will see the Error Boundary Fallback

In **production** the error stack will not be shown and users will only see the Error Boundary Fallback.

Comment: This is the intended behavior of error boundary during the development and during production, the error message will display instead of the completely white screen. When we hit the X close button the actual fallback error message is displayed.

Comment: Thanks -  your comment was written more clearly than my answer was. I have updated my answer to match.